# Nested routes, passing :user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-routes

I would like to create New Task button which will redirect to `/users/:user_id/tasks/new` 
**Routes:**

```
  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    resources :tasks, shallow: true
  end
```

**Task Controller:**

```
  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end
```

**View:**

```
<%= link_to "New Task", new_user_task_path(@user) %>
```

but it gives me - `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"tasks", :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:user_id]` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having `new_user_task_path(@user)` you would like to have probably `new_user_task_path(current_user)`. `@user` is `nil` in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried with current_user once and no idea why it didn't work, maybe restart of rails server was needed.